# Android Apps not running at all - CPU may be pegged

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt, bluestacks

I am a beginner with Android. I had done a couple of small projects to learn android. But when i tried to do one of the earlier projects again, the emulator showed app failure. I tried bluestacks, yet the same. And when I tried to run some of my previous apps which was already installed in the emulator, I figured out that, none of those apps, which were previously working is working right now. I tried debugging one of the apps, that was previously working, without making any change in the code, and got the logcat output as below(Sorry for pasting the entire thing, but I cant actually figure out the actual problem):

```
04-12 12:37:42.340: D/dalvikvm(7591): GC_CONCURRENT freed 435K, 55% free 2670K/5831K, external 716K/1038K, paused 0ms+0ms
04-12 12:37:42.750: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 2 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:43.760: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 3 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:44.770: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 4 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:44.880: I/InputDispatcher(7156): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}.  425890.0ms since event, 425890.0ms since wait started
04-12 12:37:44.880: I/WindowManager(7156): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}
04-12 12:37:45.780: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 5 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:46.790: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 6 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:47.800: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 7 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:48.810: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 8 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:49.820: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 9 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:49.890: I/InputDispatcher(7156): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}.  430900.0ms since event, 430900.0ms since wait started
04-12 12:37:49.890: I/WindowManager(7156): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}
04-12 12:37:50.830: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 10 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:51.840: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 11 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:52.850: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 12 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:53.860: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 13 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:54.870: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 14 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:54.920: I/InputDispatcher(7156): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}.  435930.0ms since event, 435930.0ms since wait started
04-12 12:37:54.920: I/WindowManager(7156): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}
04-12 12:37:55.880: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 15 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:56.890: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 16 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:57.900: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 17 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:58.910: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 18 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:59.200: D/SntpClient(7156): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
04-12 12:37:59.920: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 19 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:37:59.930: I/InputDispatcher(7156): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}.  440940.0ms since event, 440940.0ms since wait started
04-12 12:37:59.930: I/WindowManager(7156): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}
04-12 12:38:00.930: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 20 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:38:01.940: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 21 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:38:02.950: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 22 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:38:03.960: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 23 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:38:04.940: I/InputDispatcher(7156): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}.  445950.0ms since event, 445950.0ms since wait started
04-12 12:38:04.940: I/WindowManager(7156): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}
04-12 12:38:04.970: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 24 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:38:05.980: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 25 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:38:06.990: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 26 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:38:08.000: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 27 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:38:09.010: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 28 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:38:09.950: I/InputDispatcher(7156): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}.  450960.0ms since event, 450960.0ms since wait started
04-12 12:38:09.950: I/WindowManager(7156): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}
04-12 12:38:10.010: W/ActivityManager(7156): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{b493a1a0 android.intent.action.TIME_TICK} - receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@b460ef08, started 10010ms ago
04-12 12:38:10.010: I/Process(7156): Sending signal. PID: 8635 SIG: 3
04-12 12:38:10.010: I/dalvikvm(8635): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
04-12 12:38:10.010: I/dalvikvm(8635): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-12 12:38:10.010: I/Process(7156): Sending signal. PID: 7156 SIG: 3
04-12 12:38:10.010: I/dalvikvm(7156): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
04-12 12:38:10.010: I/dalvikvm(7156): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-12 12:38:10.010: W/ActivityManager(7156): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{b47fe0e8 ReceiverList{b4804a98 8635 com.android.systemui/1000 remote:b460ef08}}
04-12 12:38:10.020: W/SharedBufferStack(8635): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out 29 times(identity=16, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-12 12:38:10.040: D/dalvikvm(7156): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1141K, 49% free 6226K/11975K, external 1868K/2380K, paused 10ms
04-12 12:38:10.560: I/Process(7156): Sending signal. PID: 8635 SIG: 9
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/InputDispatcher(7156): channel 'b462dea0 StatusBar (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/InputDispatcher(7156): channel 'b462dea0 StatusBar (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/InputDispatcher(7156): channel 'b47e8660 TrackingView (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/InputDispatcher(7156): channel 'b47e8660 TrackingView (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/InputDispatcher(7156): channel 'b48c8bf0 StatusBarExpanded (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/InputDispatcher(7156): channel 'b48c8bf0 StatusBarExpanded (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/ActivityManager(7156): ANR in com.android.systemui
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/ActivityManager(7156): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x40000004 (has extras) }
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/ActivityManager(7156): Load: 3.05 / 3.23 / 3.31
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/ActivityManager(7156): CPU usage from 5000ms to -540ms ago:
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/ActivityManager(7156):   0.7% 7156/system_server: 0.5% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 127 minor
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/ActivityManager(7156): 0.5% TOTAL: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/ActivityManager(7156): CPU usage from 30ms to 540ms later:
04-12 12:38:10.560: E/ActivityManager(7156): 0% TOTAL: 0% user + 0% kernel
04-12 12:38:10.560: I/WindowManager(7156): WINDOW DIED Window{b462dea0 StatusBar paused=false}
04-12 12:38:10.560: I/WindowManager(7156): WINDOW DIED Window{b47e8660 TrackingView paused=false}
04-12 12:38:10.560: I/WindowManager(7156): WINDOW DIED Window{b48c8bf0 StatusBarExpanded paused=false}
04-12 12:38:10.560: I/ActivityManager(7156): Process com.android.systemui (pid 8635) has died.
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.systemui/.statusbar.StatusBarService in 320000ms
04-12 12:38:10.560: I/ActivityManager(7156): Start proc com.android.systemui for restart com.android.systemui: pid=8647 uid=1000 gids={3002, 3001, 3003, 1015}
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x40000004 (has extras) }
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): android.os.DeadObjectException
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): at android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy.performReceive(IIntentReceiver.java:121)
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.performReceiveLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:10955)
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.deliverToRegisteredReceiverLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11017)
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.processNextBroadcast(ActivityManagerService.java:11223)
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.access$100(ActivityManagerService.java:146)
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$2.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:1089)
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-12 12:38:10.560: W/ActivityManager(7156): at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AThread.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1344)
04-12 12:38:12.400: D/dalvikvm(7591): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 55% free 2670K/5831K, external 716K/1038K, paused 0ms+0ms
04-12 12:38:14.960: I/InputDispatcher(7156): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{b48db298 token=HistoryRecord{b4899e68 com.example.asd/.MainActivity}}.  455970.0ms since event, 455970.0ms since wait started
04-12 12:48:50.160: D/dalvikvm(8181): Debugger has detached; object registry had 180 entries
04-12 12:48:50.160: I/dalvikvm(8181): ignoring registerObject request in thread=1
04-12 12:48:50.160: I/dalvikvm(8181): ignoring registerObject request in thread=1
04-12 12:48:50.160: D/AndroidRuntime(8181): Shutting down VM
04-12 12:48:50.160: W/dalvikvm(8181): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f724f0)
04-12 12:48:50.160: D/AndroidRuntime(8181): procName from cmdline: com.example.asd
04-12 12:48:50.160: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.asd
04-12 12:48:50.160: D/AndroidRuntime(8181): file written successfully with content: com.example.asd StringBuffer : ;com.example.asd
04-12 12:48:50.170: I/Process(8181): Sending signal. PID: 8181 SIG: 9
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asd/com.example.asd.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1650)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at com.example.asd.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:18)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
04-12 12:48:50.170: E/AndroidRuntime(8181): ... 11 more
```

I tried Googling for `CPU may be pegged` error, but didn't get an actual answer. And rather, all of them were talking about the same error in some advanced apps using audio and all, but the program i tried to debug was a simple Hello World app. And somewhere someone told to close and reopen the eclipse and emulator, reboot the system, I tried everything, still no luck. I am stuck up with this for the last couple of days. Google d every possibilities in the logcat and got no answer. If anyone knows what can be the issue, please help.

And if this is of use, this is the screenshot of the debugger screen.
[image]

Comment: Check `MainActivity.java` line 18

Comment: Post the MainActivity code

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with that. But I am still wondering why no other apps that was previously opened was not working because of a small error in this one app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be calling `findViewById` inside the constructor of the Activity. You should be doing this later (preferably in `onCreate()`), and only after calling `setContentView()`.